# Are all $4$-regular graphs Hamiltonian

Tags: graph-theory

It is easy to show that all connected $2$-regular graphs are Hamiltonian. The Petersen graph is a $3$-regular graph that is not Hamiltonian. 
Are there any $4$ regular graphs that are not Hamiltonian?

Thank you

Comment: Thank you all. I up voted all answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that you didn't specify **connected** graph, which is certainly necessary for Hamiltonicity.  More generally, a Hamilton cycle has the property that deleting any $k$ vertices breaks the cycle into at most $k$ connected components.  In the case $k=1$ a Hamiltonian graph must be strongly connected.

Pick your favourite $4$-regular graph $G$, and delete one edge $e$ so it has two vertices of degree $3$.  Take two copies of $G-e$, and create a new vertex that is adjacent to the four deficient vertices.  The resulting graph is $4$-regular, connected, but not strongly connected.

Also, did you try [Googling 4-regular non-Hamiltonian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meredith_graph)?  The Meredith graph is very strongly connected, $4$-regular and still not Hamiltonian.

Answer (score 14):

The answer is **no**. The graph on the picture is the smallest counterexample[image]

You can most likely generalize this construction for every $k > 4$ and deduce that you can always find connected $k$-regular graphs that are not Hamiltonian.

Answer (score 5):

However, Tutte proved that a 4-connected planar graph is Hamiltonian.

Comment: Thanks for this piece of information