# Definition of 2-factorable Graph Theory

Tags: graph-theory

I would appreciate a simpler explanation of the following info

I am confused on what the definition of 2-factor is. It sounds like a perfect matching to me, but that's not what this paper is saying

Comment: This seems like a non-standard use of "2-factorable" as applied to the coloring; there's no stated requirement in the contracted graph to use every edge across a set of subgraphs. Perhaps that also explains the non-standard use of "2-cycle" which would not usually be allowed in a 2-factor.

Answer (score 4):

**Ordinarily**... a *$k$-factor* is a $k$-regular spanning subgraph.  Thus

- A $1$-factor is a perfect matching.
- A $2$-factor will be a spanning subgraph which is a union of disjoint cycles.

This is the ordinary definition used in, say, [Petersen's $2$-factor Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-factor_theorem).

So here's an example of a graph with a $2$-factor highlighted as colored cycles:

[image]

A *$k$-factorization* is a decomposition into $k$-factors.  A graph is *$k$-factorable* if it admits a $k$-factorization.

The above graph isn't $2$-factorable because it has vertices of odd degree.

---

Judging from the (now deleted) definition, the author:

1. includes isolated edges as $2$-cycles, and
2. defines a graph as "$2$-factorable" if there exists a $2$-factor for which after contracting the cycles, we obtain another graph with a $2$-factor.

According to this definition, a $1$-factor (perfect matching) would also be a $2$-factor.  And the above graph would be $2$-factorable.

I've never seen this definition before.

Answer (score 0):

A graph $G$ is 2-factorable if and only if $G$ is $2k-regular$ for some positive integer $k$.

A perfect matching is 1-factorable. If $M$ is a perfect matching in a graph $G$, then $G[M]$ is a 1-regular spanning subgraph of $G$.

If you want a simple way of determining if a graph is 2-factorable, it must be able to be factored into Hamiltonian cycles.

Comment: Your last sentence is false: a $2$-factor is any $2$-regular spanning subgraph which is a union of disjoint cycles, not necessarily a Hamiltonian cycle. [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/237336/383078) has an example of a $4$-regular (and therefore $2$-factorable) graph which is not Hamiltonian.