# Hamiltonian paths in same degree graph

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

Suppose we have a connected graph, and all vertices of this graph have the same even degree.

Is it always true that this graph has a Hamiltonian path?

Furthermore, is it true if the degree $2k$, this graph can be split into $k$ Hamiltonian paths?

This problem is trivial for $k=1$ but I wonder if it also holds for $k>1$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237292/are-all-4-regular-graphs-hamiltonian This is a counter example for k=4. So the answer is no.

Comment: @BobLangefeld That graph has no Hamiltonian circuit.  But it does have a Hamiltonian path 2,5,10,7,3,9,1,4,8,6,0, which is what is asked in the present question.

Comment: Right my bad. In the example, you see the two leaves coming out of 9, right. Can you construct a similar 6 regular graph but with 3 leaves? Or any 2k regular graph with 3 or more leaves? If your conjecture is false, I expect a counterexample to have leaves around one central vertex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G_1,\ldots,G_6$ be six copies of $K_7$.  Consider the graph obtained by taking $G_1,\ldots,G_7$ and one "central" vertex $c$ and making the following changes to the edges.

- Label vertices $a_k,b_k$ in each $G_k$.
- Remove every edge $a_kb_k$.
- Connect every $a_k$ to $c$.
- Connect $b_1$ to $b_2$ and $b_3$ to $b_4$ and $b_5$ to $b_6$.

Sorry this is a bit obscure, and I am no good at posting pictures.  But if you draw your own diagram I am sure you will see what I mean.

Then every vertex has degree $6$.  In any path including all vertices we would have to have (without loss of generality) vertices in $G_1\cup G_2$; followed by $c$; followed by vertices in $G_3\cup G_4$; but then the only way to continue the path is to repeat $c$.  So there is no Hamiltonian path.

**Simpler example**, inspired by [Are all $4$-regular graphs Hamiltonian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237292/are-all-4-regular-graphs-hamiltonian).

Take three copies $G_1,G_2,G_3$ of $K_7$, in each one remove an edge $a_kb_k$ and join both $a_k$ and $b_k$ to $c$.

Comment: Is it possible to construct a similar counterexample for degree 4 graph?

Comment: I thought about it a bit and couldn't come up with anything.

Comment: Take four copies of $K_5$, in each one remove an edge $a_k b_k$, and add *two* central vertices, joining $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$ to $c_1$ and $b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4$ to $c_2$.

Comment: Nice one @misha!!!